# How I do check if the variable exist in Mule 3.2?

Tags: variables, null, mule

How do check if the variable exist in Mule 3.2?
How create or replace a variable?

My Flow Exception is

```
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="#[myVar==null]">
                    <processor-chain>                      
                           <set-variable variableName="myVar" value="value1" doc:name="myVar"/>
                    </processor-chain>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <processor-chain>
                          <set-variable variableName="myVar" value="#[variable:myVar]" doc:name="myVar"/>                       
                    </processor-chain>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
```

"myVar==null" does not work

Answer (score 2):

if the variable is an invocation variable please try

```
flowVars['myVar'] == null
```

Worst case scenario you could do:

```
message.getProperty('myVar', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INVOCATION).
```

Please notice the scope is an enum so you should provide the canonical in a MEL expression.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use this MEL  to print in log or use in Choice component

```
 #[message.invocationProperties('myVar')] == null
```

There is a component "Message Property" which will help you remove or replace or create Mule message properties. You should use that to perform your operation.

To best find it use keyword "propert" in the search of pallets in the Mule studio and explore the various components there to suit your needs.